# Question about FindMaximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I must advise you that I am an almost total novice in mathematica.. However here is my very simple question..

I know the command FindMaximum[{f},{x}] to find the maximum point and maximum value of a function, but I'm in a situation in which I can't use it properly

In particular: let's say I have a function $\phi(\omega,\theta,\varphi)$ defined on $0\le\omega<2\pi$, $0\le \theta,\varphi <\pi/4$ and with values in $\mathbb{R}^+$. Let's also consider another function, $l(\theta,\varphi)$, defined on $0\le \theta,\varphi <\pi/4$ and with values in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

My question is: what is the command to find the intervals of $\theta$ and $\varphi$ for which the maximum value on $\omega$ of $\phi(x,y,,\theta,\varphi)$ is smaller than $l(\theta,\varphi)$?

Thank you very much

Comment: It might make your problem easier to use the trigonometric parametrization of the circle; $\phi$ will now explicitly depend on just three variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose

```
λ[ω_, θ_, ϕ_] := Sin[ω - θ] Cos[ϕ]
l[θ_, ϕ_] := 10 Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ]
```

then

[image]

```
Plot3D[{(ω /. Last@FindMaximum[λ[ω, θ, ϕ], {ω, π}]), l[θ, ϕ]}, 
    {θ, 0, π/4}, {ϕ, 0, π/4}]
```

The desired answer is the orange surface when it is above the blue surface, which is obtained from

```
 Plot3D[If[(ω /. Last@FindMaximum[λ[ω, θ, ϕ], {ω, π}]) > l[θ, ϕ], 
      (ω /. Last@FindMaximum[λ[ω, θ, ϕ], {ω, π}])], {θ, 0, π/4}, {ϕ, 0, π/4}]
```

[image]

Edited Note: `FindMaximum` finds local maxima.  Use `Maximize` instead to find global maxima but be aware that it can be much slower, two orders of magnitude for this simple case.

**Addendum**

In answer to a further question posed in a comment below,  a function describing the boundary curve can be obtained by plotting the curve, extracting its internal representation, a `List` of points, and converting the list to an `InterpolatingFunction`.

```
cp = ContourPlot[(ω /. Last@FindMaximum[λ[ω, θ, ϕ], {ω, π}]) == l[θ, ϕ], 
       {θ, 0, π/4}, {ϕ, 0, π/4}] // Quiet;
f = Interpolation[First@Cases[cp, GraphicsComplex[z_, __] -> z, Infinity]]
```

Although not a closed-form solution, `f` can be used like other functions in later calculations.  As a simple example, it can be used to recover a `Plot` of the curve.

```
Plot[f[θ], {θ, f["Domain"][[1, 1]], f["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, π/4}, {0, π/4}}, AxesLabel -> {θ, ϕ}]
```

[image]

Note that `f["Domain"]` simply provides the range in `θ` over which `f` is valid.

Comment: thank you! but can I also find equations for my orange surface? (this is what I really need)

Comment: In general, the range of `θ, ϕ` will not exist in closed form and can only be shown as a plot of some sort.

Comment: yes, but what you call "plot of some sort" is a surface (or a curve, or points) which must have an equation (at least locally). well I'm asking if I can have this equation

Comment: You could try doing a numerical fit to the boundary, which in general could be quite complicated.

Comment: can you explain me how do I do that in your example?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  By the way, if my answer above adequately addresses your question, please do not forget to up-vote and accept it.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you! just a comment: your code Plot3D[{(ω /. Last@FindMaximum[λ[ω, θ, ϕ], {ω, π}]), l[θ, ϕ]}, 
    {θ, 0, π/4}, {ϕ, 0, π/4}] plots the value of ω for which the maximum of λ is achieved for given θ and ϕ. If I wanted it to plot the maximum value I should have written Plot3D[{(λ[ω, θ, ϕ] /. Last@FindMaximum[λ[ω, θ, ϕ], {ω, π}]), l[θ, ϕ]}, 
    {θ, 0, π/4}, {ϕ, 0, π/4}], right?